# Import template to Magnolia CMS

Tags: magnolia

I'm currently working with magnolia cms 5 and I know how to import xml templates. Now I need to import html5 page template, just I did not find how in documentation, and I do not belive it is impossible.

Comment: You can always copy-paste the raw HTML5 in a freemarker (.ftl) template script.

Comment: Yes, but how can integrate template looking like this: http://gyazo.com/3c3231f9180945daa2fbb42bbcde74d3 with Magnolia?

Comment: Will some editors change the contents? If not, you can put everything (i.e., html files, folders...) in a docroot/ directory in your webapp, and these files and assets will be served exactly as they are.

Comment: Good idea. It's little embarrassing, but I can not locate folder with apps. Can you point it in relation to instalation?

Comment: Are you packaging your own WAR file or are you using the standard magnolia bundle?

Comment: Standard magnolia bundle. Currently I have another idea - integrating html5 template with spring and then with blossom connect it to magnolia. Maybe there is a simpler way, I just can not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options to achieve what you want.

- If you want editors to be able to edit content of the page, you need to put html in FTL file (that you can put on class path or create on the fly in STK/Templates) and replace editable parts with markup to be filled from the user input. You would also need to create template definition, make template available to editors and create dialog. See [Creating Magnolia Page Template](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Creating+a+page+template) for more details
- If this html is static and not editable by users, you can still put it in FTL or you can place it in /docroot/ folder to make it available under http://your-magnolia/docroot/your-webpage.html url.
- If you have magnolia module already, you can also place that html in mgnl-resources folder in your module and have it accessible via http://your-magnolia/.resources/your-webpage.html
- You can also go to STK/Resources and upload your page there and have it accessible under http://your-magnolia/resources/your-webpage.html

HTH,
Jan